# What kind of partition should I use for a shared network drive used mostly un Mac?

Tags: sharing, partition, file-sharing, ntfs, hfs

I have a 2TB external USB drive that I'm using to share things in my home network.

Now the drive is connected to my Mac Mini, that is supposed to act like a file server.

Currently the drive is partitioned using `NTFS` (via Tuxera  NTFS) because I wanted to be able to bring it with me when I visit some friends with PCs using Windows ;)

The biggest problem is that I discovered that Lion is no longer able to share NTFS, FAT or exFAT drives because Apple replaced samba with their own implementation.

In the future I plan to buy a new router that will be able to share the drive.

Now, **what partition type and setup should I use in order to minimise portability issues between OS X, Windows and Linux(Ubuntu)?**

- `NTFS` - so far not able to share it from Lion but I can r/w on all platforms if I connect it directly
- `HFS+`
- `ext3`
- `ext4`
- `exFAT`
- `FAT32` is *not an option, I want to be able to deal with big files 4GB+*

(Optional) It would also be great if you could tell me which inexpensive router can be used to share a  big drive like that without having performance issues.

Comment: You might get a better answer for what filesystem and router works best with non macs on superuser. Airport will share both HFS+, FAT16 and FAT32 USB drives. Do you consider airport express inexpensive?

Comment: Why not just use HFS+? I don't see how portability can be an issue since after all you are creating a network share?

Comment: Your question is not consistant - in one place you say drive is connect to Mac Mini - in another you ask for a router to share. The answer will differ between these two.